# What is meant by "invertible" matrices in the creation of a SNM

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, smith-normal-form

I just read up on wikipedia on the Smith Normal Matrix. But what is meant by an invertable matrix. For example if you have a start matrix with only PID values does that mean the other matrices don't have to contain PID values (for example integer values in the original, and rational in T)?

Furthermore what is meant by an invertable square matrix. Aren't all square matrices invertible since

A^-1 = adj(A) / |A|

Comment: What if the determinant of $A$ is zero?

Comment: Assuming its non-zero

Comment: You were asking whether *all* square matrices are invertible. The answer is no. Its determinant has to be a unit in the base ring (non-zero in particular). Even over a field, there are matrices with determinant zero. These are not invertible.